# react-native-router-flux - Not getting any tabs changes event after first load

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

`react-native-router-flux` tabs issue.

I already tried `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` methods.

I am using `react-native-router-flux` tabs and want to perform a check when my particular tab open but no lifecycle method called after first time we opened the app I think it's because all tabs loaded simultaneously at first tab loaded.
Is there any way to get event when tab change?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lazy` prop on your tabbar to load each tab when it's navigated to or you can use the prop `onEnter` on the scene component of each tab to tigger when the tab is navigated to.